# Does anyone allow one to get married the night after Pesach Sheni?

Tags: halacha, wedding, sefirat-ha-omer

[Rivivos Efraim Volume 2 page 266](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&st=&pgnum=266) in discussing whether one may eat roasted meat on the evening after Pesach Sheni concludes as follows.

> ופוק חזי מאי עמא דבר, שעושים חתונות מפוארות באותו לילה ואוכלים צלי ולא
>   מיחה אדם לעולם כמדומני

"And go and see what people do, they make beautiful weddings on that night and eat roasted meat and no one ever stopped them to the best of my knowledge" (my translation)

Is there a contemporary source that allows weddings on the evening after Pesach Sheni?

Comment: You mean: Is there _another_ source that allows...

Comment: @DoubleAA: No. I am pretty certain it is an error or that Chasunos means parties. However if there is a source that says it is permitted then I would accept it at face value.

Comment: @DoubleAA, have you ever seen or heard of a Chassuna on that night?

Comment: In this issue of Halachically Speaking, http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue9.pdf , the author refers to Yabia Omer O.C. 5:38 regarding a first marriage between Pesach and Shavuot. I don't have a Yabia Omer, but maybe someone who does could take a look?

Comment: Consider clarifying why it would be forbidden. Also by contemporary do you mean 20th century? 21st century? Is the Mishnah Berurah contemporary? Is R. Ovadya Yosef? Consider clarifying.